# Using external Javascript in Ionic 3+

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, import, external

I'm using the Mapwize SDK (an external Javascript library) with the newest version of Ionic. As others have noted, there are issues getting Javascript to work nicely with Typescript. I'm very new to front-end development -- I've looked at other answers and questions on here but they do not go into much detail for explanations. I would really like an excessively detailed explanation on how to get Mapwize working with Ionic. I'm able to make function calls from a test Javascript file in my .ts files, but what I need is to work with the JS library the way I can using the  tags in my HTML doc. People have said to do all my logic in the .ts file but then give no explanation on how this is done. The Mapwize SDK is in IIFE format and is thus self-invoking. I'm not able to access any of the functions in the .js file: https://github.com/Mapwize/mapwize.js-dist

If anyone is aware of how to make this integration work, please do this chap a favor and help me out!

Using:
Atom IDE
Ionic 4
Angular and Typescript

Answer (score 0):

I assume Ionic 4 is an angular application so:

- install Mapwize `npm i mapwize -s`
- import mapwize in your global script import (in angular.json, add `node_modules/mapwize/mapwize.js` in scripts list
- Declare Mapwize outside the component you want to use `declare var Mapwize: any;`
- Simply use it `const map = Mapwize.map(...)`

I hope this help you